# How to click image view and send that image in another activity through intent?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, onclicklistener

How to click an image view with ClickListener and how to send or pass that image to another activity through an intent

```
imgview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }
    });
```

I dont know the coding as I am new to android

Comment: from where u r getting that image ? drawable or server?

Comment: Why u passing image? better to passed url of image instead

Comment: @Nimesh Jani, try below code and let me know whether it is working or not.

Comment: i m getting that image from gallery

Comment: If the image is from drawable you can just pass the ID! No need to send the image! But i guess OP has to clarify that first

Comment: If you getting image from gallery then send path of that image to new activity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
 imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    i.putExtra("bmp_img", bmp);
    startActivity(i);
```

and in your second activity put this...

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");
 imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: what is intent.getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");

Comment: @Nimeshjani  intent.getParcelableExtra("Bitmap"); brings data from the intent.

Comment: @Nimeshjani for more info read this...http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

Write this in your **FirstActivity.java**

```
imgview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
             Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
             mIntent.putExtra("bmp_img", bmp);
             startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    });
```

and this is in **SecondActivity.java**

Take one image-view in your XML, and then pass this code in onCreate method

```
Bitmap mBitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("bmp_img");
imageview.setImageResource(mBitmap);
```

Replace this `R.drawable.ic_launcher` with whatever image you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

1) How to click image view

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageId);
img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // your code here
    }
});
```

2) How to send that image in another activity through intent

at First Activity.

```
    Intent currentIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivitySecond.class);
    currentIntent .putExtra("bmp_img", bmp);
startActivity(currentIntent );
```

for getting output in second activity,

in Second Activity.

```
Bitmap mBitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("bmp_img");
```

Finally you can write as follows

```
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageId);
    img .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent currentIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivitySecond.class);
    //suppose your image is simple icon launcher
                 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                 currentIntent .putExtra("bmp_img", bmp);
startActivity(currentIntent );
            }
        });
```

and now in second activity

```
 ImageView imageview= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImageId);
Bitmap mBitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("bmp_img");
imageview.setImageResource(mBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
imgview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Intent myIntent=new Intent(ThisView.this,NextView.class);
             Bundle i = new Bundle();
            i.putByte("Image", yourImage);
            myIntent.putExtras(i);
            startActivity(myIntent);


    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

    imageView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap image= imageView.getDrawingCache();

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap", image);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

In Another Activity call llike below.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("imagebitmap");

image.setImageBitmap(bmp );
```